# python Infinite loop ending unexpectedly

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite

When running this code program will randomly stop, it gives no errors it just stops it also never gets to flag3, I tested this with just the flags no motor control same problem, could i be overloading somthing, and it just quits out, Please Help

```
import time
import display
import servo
import moter
import pic
import button


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


def main():
    GPIO.cleanup()
    moter.init()
    servo.init()
    display.init()
    pic.init()
    moter.start()
    #servo.start()
    try:
        while True:
            d = pic.mesure()
            print "Flag1"
            while d > 100:
                moter.start()
                moter.forward(90)
                d = pic.mesure()
                print d
            moter.stop_drive()
            print "Flag2"
        print "Flag3"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        pass
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #debug("----------========== Starting session! ==========----------")
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `break` in the `while True:` loop - why do you expect it to ever end ?

Answer (score 0):

It *won't* get to `flag3`. Ever!

It will either run the outer loop forever, get stuck in one of the `pic` or `moter` (sic) calls, or raise an exception and exit.

The output of the program will be invaluable in figuring out which of those cases is actually occurring.

For example, do you see `flag1`? What about `flag2`? Or all the `d` values?

Put a `print` in the exception area and after the `try` block and see if *that* comes out.

If you don't have a `print` statement every couple of lines during debugging, you're not taking it seriously :-)

Comment: I dont think its the subroutines because i had commented them out and still had the same issue,

Comment: and LOL ill add in some more Prints so far i get flag 1 and 2 but ill add some more to see whats up thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is an exception being thrown. Try printing the exception to see where the problem is or remove the try block and see which line it errors at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the program is stopping but simply it cant do anything after that. you initiate the while statement and it runs through the code and then isn't told to stop so it starts from the top of the statement but there isn't anything for it to do so it starts over. You could try:

```
while True:
    d = pic.mesure()
    print "Flag1"
    while d > 100:
        moter.start()
        moter.forward(90)
        d = pic.mesure()
        print d
    moter.stop_drive()
    print "Flag2"
    break
print "Flag3"
```

This will stop the loop and continue the program.